# PHP - Trazer resultado com casas decimais em select no banco de dados firebird

Tags: php, sql, firebird

Como trazer as casas decimais (,00) no retorno do meu array após a consulta ao banco de dados usando PHP?

Veja resultado da consulta;

```
array(2)
{
    ["COD_PRODUTO"]=>string(9) "AM0038784"
    ["PRECO"]=>float(700)
}
array(2)
{
    ["COD_PRODUTO"]=>string(9) "AM0038784"
    ["PRECO"]=>float(700)
}
array(2)
{
    ["COD_PRODUTO"]=>string(9) "AM0038784"
    ["PRECO"]=>float(700)
}
```

Veja meu código PHP;

```
require_once 'function/_Global.php';

$data_busca_inicial = data_timer_data_hora_inicial();
$data_busca_final = data_timer_data_hora_final();

$sql = "
    SELECT  

        PRODUTOS.COD_PRODUTO,
        PRECOS.PRECO
      FROM
        PRODUTOS,
        PRECOS
WHERE
        PRECOS.produto = PRODUTOS.produto
        AND TABELA='89'
        AND TIPO_PROD='AC'
        AND DATA_ATUALIZACAO >'$data_busca_inicial'
        AND DATA_ATUALIZACAO <'$data_busca_final'
        ORDER BY  PRODUTOS.COD_PRODUTO 
            ";

$query= ibase_query ($dbh, $sql);
ibase_free_result($query);//Libera a memoria usada
ibase_close($dbh);//fecha conexão com o firebird

while ($row = ibase_fetch_assoc  ($query)) 
{
    var_dump($row);         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a função [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php) do PHP.

Veja como fica no seu caso:

```
$foo = (float) 700;
$bar = (float) 700.00;

echo '$foo formatada com casas decimais: '.number_format($foo, 2, ',', ''); // 700,00
echo '$bar formatada com casas decimais: '.number_format($bar, 2, ',', ''); // 700,00
```

Em dados do tipo `float`, as casas decimais são simplificadas quando terminam em `0` (zero(s)). Se na sua consulta retornasse algum valor com as casas decimais diferentes de `0`, seria retornado assim: `700.12` ou `700.4`...

> Leitura recomendada: [PHP - Números de ponto flutuante](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php)